# How can I create a chat app message input

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm using angular so solutions with document.xyz wouldn't work for me
Sounds like a stupid question, but I've tried everything. I know I just need a little bit of css magic to make it work, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. I want a message input in my chat app that expands when you press shift+enter(up to like 50% of the height, but that's easy with max-height: 50vh) and the message gets sent when you press enter. If any of you know discord, basically that chat form.
This is the message-form component:

```html
<div class="message-form">
    <textarea #textarea class="textarea" type="text" (keydown.enter)="sendMessage()" [(ngModel)]="messageToBeSent"
        role="textbox">
    </textarea>
    <button (click)="sendMessage()">Send Message</button>
</div>
```

The styles for the textarea:

```css
resize: none;
overflow: visible;
max-height: 50vh;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Don't expect anyone to write code from scratch. *"I tried everything"* show the *try* you're most content with.

Comment: Sorry for responding late, but I've edited it now. I managed to implement the correct displaying of the messages with the newlines and also the scroll behaviour, where it scrolls you to the bottom. Thanks for your feedback!